# How can I set the style html, body {height: 100%} programatically with vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

In my css file I have the rule:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
```

I don't want to have to rely on the stylesheet so can I set this style using vanilla javascript? If so how?

Comment: you can try this `document.querySelector('body').style.height = '100%'`

Comment: I would set css classes, and have the style done with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll('html, body')` to select both elements, then iterate over the result set with the help of `forEach()`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('html, body').forEach(node => node.style.height = '100%');
```

Please note this won't work in IE 11 because it doesn't support `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` (and also because it uses an arrow function).

For IE 11 you can use `Function.prototype.call()`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('html, body'), 
  function(node) { node.style.height = '100%'; }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
document.querySelector('body').style.height = '100%';
```